# Inject dependency on Junit5 extension registration

Tags: java, junit, junit5

In my project I implemented a JUnit 5 extension similar to this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FakeExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Do something with " + dataSource);
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to use it ina Spring Boot test, this way:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class FakeTest {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @RegisterExtension
    FakeExtension ext = new FakeExtension(dataSource);

    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Run test");
    }

}
```

As expected, this isn't working, but **I'd like to find a way to register a JUnit extension passing a parameter that is initialized on test class creation**, *possibly in framework-agnostic way* (not necessarily usign `@Autowired`).

Taking a look a [JUnit docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-programmatic-instance-fields) I can't find a suitable solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating the data-source yourself you can create a "BeforeAllCallback" extension like this:

```
 class DataSourceExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    private final String jdbcUrl;
    private final String user;
    // ...

    private DataSource dataSource;

    DataSourceExtension(File config) {
        // read config from File, InputStream, Resource ... whatever you prefer
    }

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        // initialize data-source from config
        this.dataSource = ...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        // clean up dataSource
    }
}
```

In your tests you can then register the extensions:

```
@Order(0)
@RegisterExtension
static final DataSourceExtension DS_EXT = new DataSourceExtension("...");

@Order(1)
@RegisterExtension
FakeExtension ext = new FakeExtension(DS_EXT.dataSource());
```